# trying to execute a bash script on the same server(different project) from codeigniter, but the script returns 504

Tags: php, bash, codeigniter

I made a method in controller that checks the environment and runs shell_exec('. /var/scripts/somescript.sh') from there and outputs a message

this is the sample code

```
/**
 * Run this script
 */
function my_script()
{
    if ($this->params['purge'])
    {
        if ($this->is_ajax())
            {
                if(ENVIRONMENT == 'production') 
                {
                     $data['output'] = shell_exec(". /var/prod/www/script.sh 2>&1");
                     $data['message'] = "Task completed";
                }
                elseif(ENVIRONMENT == 'staging')
                {
                    $data['output'] = shell_exec(". /var/stag/www/script.sh 2>&1");
                    $data['message'] = "Task completed";
                }
                elseif(ENVIRONMENT == 'testing') 
                {
                    $data['output'] = shell_exec(". /var/dev/www/script.sh 2>&1");
                    $data['message'] = "Task Completed";
                }
                $this->output_json(true, $data, array('key_order'=>true));
            }
    }

    $this->add_js('tools/my_file');
    $this->view->breadcrumbs()->add('Run the script');
    $this->display('tools/myfile.php');
}
```

Now I made a view and with a button that triggers this codeigniter method through javascript

```
$(function() {
$('.btn-purge').click(function() {

    if (confirm("This will run the aforementioned script, Click OK to confirm"))
    {
         $.get('/dashboard/tools/my_file?purge=1', function(rtn) {

             if (rtn.status !== true)
             {
                 alert("Failed to run script");
             }
             else
             {
                 //alert(rtn.data)
                 $("pre.result").css("display", "block");
                 $("pre.result").text(rtn.data.output);
             }
          });
    }

});
```

});

Now this script.sh is present in other project hosted on the same server and has ~10 miniutes execution time.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's not obvious what you have already tried to do to solve this problem. What is the expected result, and what is the actual result? Is any data returned to the client at all? Is it trying to run the script but failing? Have you put any debugging into the shell script to see if it is getting invoked? If you use `exec()` instead of `shell_exec()` do you get a useful exit code?

Comment: @jerry the script is part of a symphony project and is responsible for clearing caches and populate the indexes of that application. Now this script runs just fine as the cronjob and displays message "Cache cleared" after it has executed.
Now i can't figure why i can't trigger it from the code, i tried creating a small bash script in my local environment and tried triggering it from this view and it works.